# Script Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, yahoo-api

Script Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed. What should I do? I click Yes, and my web page isn't displayed.

At the beginning of my Product page code, I have: http://pastebin.com/iiUfMq1v

Everything works fine in every browser except IE8, that is the only browser that is throwing any sort of error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery instead of YUI?

Comment: My bad. Thought they were also using jQuery in some way, I don't fully understand how the script works.

Comment: Why does it look like you are using both jQuery and YUI?

Comment: I completely missed the `$(document).ready(function(){` at the top.

Answer (score 6):

Please check these links

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/html-parsing-error-unable-to-modify-the-parent/e64759e0-d344-42d6-b1d8-0ce27504dd71

http://afewguyscoding.com/2010/03/message-html-parsing-error-unable-to-modify-the-parent-container-element-before-the-child-element-is-closed-kb927917/

Basically it will happen when you try to update a element by javascript which is the parent of current element or the element does not render at all.  I faced this issue and fixed by running the script after the page loads. i.e inside `$(document).ready()`

hope this helps someone..

Comment: For me the resolution was to move the offending JQuery method call to another place outside the parent (as suggested in third link). This problem happened only on _some_ IE 8 browsers (possibly un-patched browsers, as suggested in first link).

Answer (score 1):

IE has historically not allowed the DOM to be modified until after the domReady event.

Comment: Ok, how do I determine, with my code at: http://pastebin.com/iiUfMq1v 

When the DOM is ready?

Comment: Because then, if I know how to determine if it's ready, then I can call my code?

Comment: When using YUI, subscribe to the domReady event.